Django Form using fields from multiple models
I have the following in my models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class DPlaces(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant

class DEntry(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(DPlaces, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e4date = models.DateField(blank=False)

I have the following in my forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import DEntry, DPlaces

class DEntryFilterForm(forms.Form):
    place = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DPlaces.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=False,
    )
    e4date = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=DEntry.objects.order_by().values_list('e4date', flat=True).distinct(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        required=False,
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DEntryFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['place'].queryset = DPlaces.objects.all()
        self.fields['e4date'].queryset = DEntry.objects.values_list('e4date', flat=True).distinct()

in my views.py file I have
def entrytable_view(request):
    data_entries = DEntry.objects.all()
    filtered_entries = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = DEntryFilterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
              # Do Something

The form works and form.is_valid returns true if a choice on 'place' field is selected but fails and form.is_valid returns false if a choice on 'e4date' field is selected.
I suspect this is because the e4date field is not on the DPlaces model (it is on the DEntry model), but I am not sure. I any case, I am clueless on how to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

You can check the errors of a form really easy with form.errors. So you can change your logic to see the actual errors like this:
    data_entries = DEntry.objects.all()
    filtered_entries = None

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = DEntryFilterForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
              # Do Something
        else:
              print(form.errors)


There are no form errors. It has field errors stating e4date is not a valid value. The value   seems to be ok when I print it.
